# How to change ConfigParser.RawConfigParser module behaviour

Tags: python, configparser

I want to change default output of `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.items(section)` and also set `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.optionxform = str` in ConfigParser module, so I created my own module `MyConfigParser` inheriting `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser` as base class. Below is its code which I think is incorrect. Also I am unable to use it.

```
import os
import ConfigParser

class MyConfigParser(ConfigParser.RawConfigParser):
    """
    """

    ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.optionxform = str

    def items(section):
        items_list = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.items(section)
        for item in item_list:
            index = item_list.index(item)
            if not (os.path.exists(item[1]) and os.path.isfile(item[1])):
                item_list.pop(index)
        return items_list
```

Comment: @CppLearner How to make this code work, cause I think its incorrect.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your new implementation? What is it that you can't get from the original implementation? These information are missing. And why do you think your code doesn't work? What does "incorrecT" mean to you? It's too vague to answer.

Comment: @CppLearner I using `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()` to parser a config file, I just want to tweak its `ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.items()` module. If I am correct its done using Inheritance. But the module I wrote is not working.

Comment: could you provide some minimal dummy input config file and the desired output? You could also include the code that tries to read that file and the (incorrect) output that it produces.